# I need to upload folder in ASP.NET Web API swagger UI

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I need to perform drag and drop the folder for ASP.NET Web API Swagger UI, I have searched some sources, it helps me to upload multiple files but not able to upload folder. So is there any way to perform drag and drop the folder.

I tried to upload folder but I am only uploading one file.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a folder isn't possible in swagger UI. It allows upload of multiple files though.
If you need to preserve the folder structure and structure of inner items, the workaround would be zip the folder and upload the zipped file.
More details can be found in the [Swagger specifications](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/)